# Laravel blade not showing CSS on specific page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

Laravel 6.0 not show one specific page's css. Others page works smoothly.
This is my code
"satisekle.blade.php and edit.blade.php almost same page. only difference is some variable. php code is working but css is not loaded. My assets folder in public/assets

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/dist/img/ico/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- jquery-ui css -->
    <link href="assets/plugins/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Bootstrap rtl -->
    <!--<link href="assets/bootstrap-rtl/bootstrap-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->
    <!-- Lobipanel css -->
    <link href="assets/plugins/lobipanel/lobipanel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Pace css -->
    <link href="assets/plugins/pace/flash.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Pe-icon -->
    <link href="assets/pe-icon-7-stroke/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Themify icons -->
    <link href="assets/themify-icons/themify-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

```html
<head>
    @include('partials._head')
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
@include('partials.topbar')
<div class="container" id="contentall">
    <div class="content">
        @include('partials.leftbar')
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</div>
</body>

@include('partials.javascript')
```

**Blade**

```php
@extends('main')
@section('content')
    <form action="{{ route('satislar.store') }}" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Satış Takip Numarası</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="{{$random}}" name="satis_takip_no">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Random Atanan Unique Takip Numarası</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Ürün</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                   name="urun" placeholder="Ürün">*
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ürün İsmini Giriniz</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Birim</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="birim"
                   placeholder="Birim">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ürün Miktarını Giriniz</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Firma Adı</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                   name="firma" placeholder="Firma Adı">*
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Firmanın Adını Giriniz</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Yetkili</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="yetkili"
                   placeholder="Yetkili">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Teslim Alacak Yetkilinin İsmini Giriniz</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Telefon</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="telefon"
                   placeholder="Telefon">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ulaşılacak Kişinin Telefon Numarasını Giriniz</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">E-Posta</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                   name="eposta" placeholder="E-Posta">*
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Satışı Takip edecek Kişinin E-postasını Giriniz</small>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Gönder</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

**Controller**

```php
public function satisekle()
{
    $number = mt_rand(1000000000, mt_getrandmax());
    if ($this->sorgula($number) === "") {
        return $this->satisekle();
    }

    return view('satislar.satisekle')->with('random', $number);
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $satis = Satislar::find($id);

    return view('satislar.edit')->with('satis', $satis);
}
```

and route;

```html
Route::get('/satisekle', 'satislarController@satisekle');
Route::get('/index', 'satislarController@index');
Route::get('/satislar/{$id}/edit', 'satislarController@edit');

Route::resource('satislar', 'satislarController');
```

and this is not working. not show css i'm completely crazy;

```html
@extends('main')


@section('content')

    <form action="{{ route('satislar.update',$satis->id)}}" method="post">
        @method('PUT')
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Satış Takip Numarası</label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control"  value="{{$satis->takip_no}}" name="satis_takip_no" readonly>
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Random Atanan Unique Takip Numarası</small>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Ürün</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="exampleInputEmail1" value="{{$satis->urun}}" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="urun" placeholder="Ürün">*
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ürün İsmini Giriniz</small>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Birim</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="{{$satis->birim}}" name="birim" placeholder="Birim">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ürün Miktarını Giriniz</small>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Firma Adı</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="{{$satis->firma}}" name="firma" placeholder="Firma Adı" required>*
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Firmanın Adını Giriniz</small>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Yetkili</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="yetkili" value="{{$satis->yetkili}}" placeholder="Yetkili">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Teslim Alacak Yetkilinin İsmini Giriniz</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Telefon</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="telefon" value="{{$satis->telefon}}" placeholder="Telefon">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ulaşılacak Kişinin Telefon Numarasını Giriniz</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">E-Posta</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="eposta" value="{{$satis->eposta}}" placeholder="E-Posta" required>*
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Satışı Takip edecek Kişinin E-postasını Giriniz</small>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Gönder</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

Comment: Please show the code where you load your css.

Comment: all my css in public/assets

like <link href="assets/plugins/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: Edit your question and post the code where you load the css please. It's probably the only code needed

Comment: Please try to add a slash to your href, i.e.: `<link href="/assets` or better use the laravel asset() [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset)

Comment: its ok i guess. 2 blade file in same folder. and extends same code. assets should be loaded.

Comment: Have you tried to add the slash? is it working now or not?

Comment: yes, slash is perfectly working but i secure my work and i use asset() and its done thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO it's better if you use the `asset()` [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset) to load your assets, e.g.:

```php
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('dist/img/ico/favicon.png') }}" type="image/x-icon">
<!-- jquery-ui css -->
<link href="{{ asset('plugins/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- Bootstrap rtl -->
<!--<link href="{{ asset('bootstrap-rtl/bootstrap-rtl.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->
<!-- Lobipanel css -->
<link href="{{ asset('plugins/lobipanel/lobipanel.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- Pace css -->
<link href="{{ asset('plugins/pace/flash.css" rel="stylesheet') }}" type="text/css"/>
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="{{ asset('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- Pe-icon -->
<link href="{{ asset('pe-icon-7-stroke/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- Themify icons -->
<link href="{{ asset('themify-icons/themify-icons.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

You can read in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls) on the various type of relative and absolute URLs for `href=` and which are better to use.